# Trying to gather the right documents for my next application

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, russian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

I was refused a visit visa to the UK and I'm trying to apply again, but I'm still confused on how to answer some questions.

- cost of trip to you personally
- cost of flights or ship
- how much do you have for the trip?
- cost of living expenses while in the UK.

Please take note that my uncle is sponsoring the whole trip.

What is required of me? I'm not really getting that part well.

With my bank statement, is there a required amount I'm supposed to have? I'm really confused.

I'm a student who's not working and receives money from home every month, but had received money from home that amounted to about 300GBP as at the time I was making my application, to help me get some things for my application.  (For example, I had to travel from my city to a different city since there was no application centre where I'm located, and the transport is very expensive.) But they said there's no evidence of source of the money in my account, given that I'm a student who's not working, so I still don't know which evidence they want.

I'm schooling in a different country. I receive money from home via my home country's account and withdraw with the Visa card where I am currently, then deposit the money into my current country of residence's account.

Comment: Would you please add the consulate where you are applying?  I can try to edit my answer with any additional information specific to that consulate.  Thanks.

Comment: Your question was really hard to read as a "wall of text".  I have taken the liberty of trying to break it up a little, and improving the punctuation for easier reading.  Please feel free to improve it further.  (By the way, in standard English, you should put a space after any of the punctuation marks `. , ? ! ; :`.)

Comment: Applied from Russia @gayotfow

Comment: @deitz, ok... amended.  And a tip of the hat to Nate for a saving edit!

Answer (score 5):

You are asking what to put down to questions on the UK entry clearance form, and invariably the answer is taken from 'best practices':  *write down the correct answers*.  If the form calls for an explicit number like `What is the cost to you personally?`  You are in a position to know this figure and would write it down.  If you do not know the figure, then your application may be misconceived and you should wait until you have the answers.

If the cost to you personally is 0, then put down 0.  If you do not know the total cost of your trip, put down that you do not know or ask your uncle what the right figure is and then write it down.

Aunts and uncles do not qualify as close family.  The part where you had to check 'other' because 'uncle' does not appear as a choice means that you were filling out a part of the form they told you to *SKIP*. This can be fixed by reading the guidance carefully.

Sometimes people have questions like yours because they are in reduced circumstances and believe giving the 'real' answers will have a negative impact on the decision.  So they want to know what to put down for an answer instead of the 'real' answer, and this generally leads to refusals (per your previous question).  They do not require a specific amount to appear in your bank account, you should put down the current balance or the balance from your most recent statement.  Also, they do not refuse on lack of money where there is a **valid** and **trustworthy** sponsor.

Part 8 of the form is devoted to 3rd party sponsors.  They are smart enough to look in that part of the form if it is filled out.  If your uncle is offering to sponsor your visit, write it down.  Then get your uncle to explain why he is doing that and to submit all of his documents on your behalf.  If he does not own his house, he should additionally submit permission from the landlord for you to stay there.  He should also write an undertaking to remain in the UK during the course of your visit.  Expect your uncle's premise to be thoroughly challenged, so it needs to be well founded in order to succeed.

Between his evidence and your evidence there should be no gaps. If a given piece of evidence is missing, you can explain why.

Your discussion about being a student and how you are receiving support for that was somewhat unclear, but I gather your previous refusal mentioned that ***provenance of funds*** was an issue.  It's a very common source of problems and there's lots of existing material here on the site discussing it...

- [Can I convince embassies to accept my overpaid credit card as a proof of funds?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/can-i-convince-embassies-to-accept-my-overpaid-credit-card-as-a-proof-of-funds/45681#45681)
- [Uk visa got refused due to unexplained deposits. How to re-apply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50590/uk-visa-got-refused-planning-to-re-apply/50591#50591)
- [UK visa refused due to sloppy documentation. How should I reapply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44771/applying-for-uk-visa-after-refusal/45812#45812)
- [UK PLAB Visa Refusal due to unexplained bank deposits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42820/uk-plab-visa-refusal/43122#43122)
- [UK visa bank statement info](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48380/uk-visa-bank-statement-info/48428#48428)

These came from people with provenance of funds issues similar to yours.  Please read them and see how well they can help you devise a better strategy for your next application.  If not, you can then ask a really specific question that has not been covered previously.

---

**Adding some General information about UK visit applications in Russia.**

You will submit your application to a Visa Application Centre (a commercially outsourced station) and they will forward it to the regional hub in Moscow.  Moscow is a great consulate with a success rate percentage in the high 90's. It means not very many people get refused.  They have an enviable turn-around time. For your specific case, they have lots of experience in 3rd party sponsorship and will happily approve them in a few days when all of the stuff dovetails.  As mentioned, they do not have that many refusals, and when they do it is passed to the higher ups for an additional review to make sure the refusal is justified.

Comment: They said I applied to to visit my aunt (which I never stated in my application) but brought supporting documents from my uncle stating his willingness to bear the cost of my trip, meaning there's no personal or professional relation between us (actually when filling the form there was a question that went like what's the relation of the person in the UK to you but there wasn't uncle in the options provided so I chose other relative and added his contact details and address so I don't know where the aunt came from, does choosing other relative mean aunt or something?)
I was surprised with that

Comment: With the part that was unclear to you, they said I stated in my application I'm a non working student and that I attached a bank statement with a closing balance of over 200GBP and that they aren't satisfied with the evidence of the source or the money is for my exclusive use. I was trying to say I received that amount from home to help me pay for the application and a trip from my city to the city where the application centre is located but the consular doubted the source of that amount,which evidence did they need to show that amount was genuinely mine?

Comment: Please with the answers to these questions; cost of trip to you personally,

cost of flights or ship,

how much do you have for the trip?,

cost of living expenses while in the UK, in the case where my uncle is the sponsor,am I required to state figures or put in nothing and explain to them later on in my application that my uncle is sponsoring that's why I didn't put in the amount there? I hope after correcting all these, I won't be rejected again.

Comment: I'm able to compute that, actually I put in the right figure during my application but was rejected stating I had insufficient balance in my account, thus I couldn't meet the cost of my trip, meanwhile I'm not working so my uncle was bearing all the cost of my trip so I need help on how to answer those questions in my next application. Hope you get me

Comment: @deitz anything that your uncle is paying for should not be counted add part of the "cost of the trip to you."  In other words, if the trip costs £1000 and he is paying £950 then you should put £50.

Comment: @deitz, did you read the paragraph above that starts with "Part 8 of the form..."?   And do you understand your previous application you filled out the wrong form?  I really don't understand your confusion... :(

Comment: @deitz, start over and do not click on 'family visitor'.  You do not qualify as a family visitor, please read the guidance!

Comment: Please with reference to my question, with the second and fourth points, if I get you rightly it means they are both zero because I am not paying for any of those and with how much do I have for my trip, am I expected to write what I have in my account.? @phoog

Comment: Yes, I think so.  The money in your account is available to you.  Even if you do not plan to spend it, you could spend it if you needed to, for example if emergency or other unanticipated expenses were to arise.  The guidance is available on the same UK site that explains everything else about visas.  There is a page about documents you must provide for a standard visitor visa, and one link on that page is "read the guidance."

Comment: @deitz here's the link; I was using my phone before and it's difficult to paste links into comments there: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents